Why can't I find the range of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$?
$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$. Now $f(x) = y$; and $x = g(y)$.
Range of $f(x)$ = Domain of $g(y)$
$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$
$y^2 = \frac{1}{{x-5}}$
$x = \frac {1 + 5y^2}{y^2}$
Clearly, the domain of the above function is $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$
But the range of $f(x) = (0, \infty)$?

When you square both sides of an equation you can introduce new solutions, just like squaring of $x=3$ gives $x^2=9$ which also has $x=-3$ as a solution.

For the function:
$$
x=\frac{1+5y^2}{y^2}
$$
has a domain of $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ as you said. But it does not mean the function $$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$$ has the same range. Because, if you see:
$$
x=\frac{1+5y^2}{y^2}\\\Rightarrow y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}
$$
which indeed has a range of $\mathbb R-\{0\}$. In this case, the validation is correct.
But to find the range of the above function, we first find the domain:
$$
\text{Dom} f(x)=(5,\infty)$$
Putting this marginal values of the interval set in the function we find the range as:
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 5} f(x)\rightarrow \infty$$
and
$$
lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)\rightarrow 0
$$
Therefore, the range of the function is $(0,\infty)$

Does this method work universally on all functions?

Probably it does, but I have not checked.

@MathMathMath you need to have a continuous function on the domain for this to work

I recommend thinking about this a little less computationally and more as this function being collection of simpler functions composed with each other that move the domain around for the next function in the chain. Like, what's the first thing we do to $x$? We subtract 5. What's the range there? Well, $(-\infty, \infty)$. Then what do we do? We take the square root of that. As it is traditionally defined, the square root function is only defined on non-negative numbers and from there, it spits out all the non-negative numbers, that is the range there is $[0, \infty)$. Then we take the reciprocal of that. We can't do that to zero, so where does taking the reciprocal of numbers take $(0, \infty)$?
I hope that gives you more of a feeling where the answer is coming from.
